# See a list of users logged in using LDAP

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, ldap

I helped set up a computer lab with a LDAP setup to share home folders and to use for user login.

The server running ldap is centos and the computers connecting to it are linux mint.  People can get to the server by ssh, but if they are in the lab they can just login.  When they are logged in by ssh they show up with the w or who command, but not if they login with the lab computer.  Is there a way to see who is logged in including if they are using a lab computer?

Thanks for the help.